# How to fix Duplicate class error when migrating to Mapbox 11

Tags: mapbox-android, mapbox-android-maps, mapbox-android-nav

I am working on migrating to Mapbox 11 from Mapbox 10, but I get Duplicate class error. I tried to exclude the duplicated class, but no luck.

```
Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener found in modules jetified-common-24.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.0.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.1-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.1)
Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager found in modules jetified-common-24.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.0.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.1-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.1)
Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager$AccuracyAuthorization found in modules jetified-common-24.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.0.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.1-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.1)
Duplicate class com.mapbox.common.module.okhttp.CallbackWrapper found in modules jetified-common-24.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.0.0) and jetified-okhttp-21.3.1-runtime (com.mapbox.common:okhttp:21.3.1)
```

I tried to exclude the duplicated class, but it didn't work.

```
implementation ("com.mapbox.maps:android:11.0.0", {
    exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-android-core'
})
implementation ("com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-offline-v9:0.9.0", {
    exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module:'mapbox-android-telemetry'
    exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module:'mapbox-android-telemetry-okhttp3'
    exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-android-core'
})
implementation ("com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.42.6", {
    exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module:'mapbox-android-telemetry'
    exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module:'mapbox-android-telemetry-okhttp3'
    exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-android-core'
})
implementation ("com.mapbox.navigation:android:2.5.1", {
    exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-android-core'
})
```

I expected the build error would be fixed after excluding duplicate class, but resulted in the same error. How can I fix this?